# constraint path planning ur5

Tags: motion-planning, moveit, path, ros-industrial, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I am following this tutorial
http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Tutorials/Create_a_MoveIt_Pkg_for_an_Industrial_Robot

in order to move my real ur5. So far I get the simulated robot running using the demo.launch file from
https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot.

After specifying a desired end-effector position in the cartesian frame ( in the rviz gui) I often receive path planning which seems to be not very cost efficient. Furthermore, my robot will be mounted on a flat surface which means that the robot will collide in case any point is below z=0 of the base(world) frame.

How can I constrain the path planning in order to only get paths wich are limited to my reachable task space?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194465/constraint-path-planning-ur5/) by [psfa_fz](https://answers.ros.org/users/20415/psfa_fz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2014-10-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Personally I'd only use CollisionObjects for objects that you need to be able to add to and remove from a scene. For (semi) static objects I'd use one of the object representation formats that ROS supports.

1. Create a sufficiently detailed 'work cell' and add it to your URDF: you mention a 'flat surface' (table?) on which your robot is mounted. Model your environment, including the table and any other objects / obstacles that are in your cell. Besides restricting the planning space, this also helps visualisation. You will have to (re)generate a MoveIt configuration package for the combination of work cell & manipulator URDF.
2. Use the MoveIt `.scene` format to describe your work cell and load that using the appropriate APIs (or button in RViz).

See the [MoveIt Environment Representation](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/Environment_Representation/Rviz) tutorial for some pointers on this.

You can find an example of a URDF of a modelled work cell in [Exercise 3.1 - Workcell XACRO](http://ros-industrial.github.io/industrial_training/_source/session3/Workcell-XACRO.html) of the ROS-Industrial Training Exercises.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1